# When i open a file to get strings from it and transform them in int's it will give out nothing>

Tags: python, text-files

I have a .txt file that has numbers in strings and I try extracting them and turn them in int's to store them into a list, that later on, I will plot into a graph with matplotlib. When I try turning them into integers it does nothing and shows that their type is still .
I have tried to move the things around or to open the text file in some other way, still didn't work.
Here is the code snippet I put together.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = []

with open('to_graph.txt', 'r') as f:
for line in f:
    try:
        int(line)
    except ValueError:
        print("we found a letter in your graphing data ")
        continue
    if line == int :
        x.append(line)

print(x)
```

the text file has numbers on each line, one number a line.

Comment: `if line == int` That is not the right way to ask "is line an integer?"

Comment: The line `if line == int:` is incorrect, use this instead `if isinstance(line, int):` the `ininstance` function take two params, first one being the target being checked, second being the type you want to check against e.g. `int`, `string`, `float`. As `int` isn't a normal key word you can't use it normally like that.

Answer (score 1):

You are converting line into `int` by `int(line)` but not storing it.
Try the following:

```
line=int(line)
```

And replace `if line == int :` this line with `if type(x)==int :`

Comment: Thank you, it worked! It's been bugging me for an hour now, thanks a lot!

Comment: Good to know it helped. Please make it as the accepted answer, if it solved your issue. @alex